# Is VHDL for digital circuits only?

Tags: analog, vhdl, circuit-design, chip-design

Both Wikipedia and other SO questions about VHDL vs Verilog mention **digital** when describing VHDL.

Can you use VHDL to design **analog** circuits?

Comment: Read about "VHDL-AMS" - for simulation only, no synthesis to the best of my knowledge. So yes, perhaps you can *design* analog using VHDL-AMS. But implementation of that design then proceeds as normal.

Comment: I think generally analog ASIC design is done in SPICE, but I'm not very familiar with it. It's something of a secret art even within the industry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in its base specification. 
VHDL stands for V(HSIC) H(ardware) D(escriptive) L(anguage) with VHSIC standing for Very High Speed Integrated Circuit.

There is an analogue extension to VHDL which is VHDL-AMS

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL-AMS

> VHDL-AMS is a derivative of the hardware description language VHDL
>   (IEEE standard 1076-1993). It includes analog and mixed-signal
>   extensions (AMS) in order to define the behavior of analog and
>   mixed-signal systems (IEEE 1076.1-1999).
>
> The VHDL-AMS standard was created with the intent of enabling
>   designers of analog and mixed signal systems and integrated circuits
>   to create and use modules that encapsulate high-level behavioral
>   descriptions as well as structural descriptions of systems and
>   components.[1]
>
> VHDL-AMS is an industry standard modeling language for mixed signal
>   circuits. It provides both continuous-time and event-driven modeling
>   semantics, and so is suitable for analog, digital, and mixed
>   analog/digital circuits. It is particularly well suited for
>   verification of very complex analog, mixed-signal and radio frequency
>   integrated circuits.

Comment: Just an addition, the active standard of VHDL-AMS is [IEEE 1076.1-2007](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1076.1-2007.html). The Wikipedia page doesn't seem up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

If **design** is the case, it is used for digital only. On the other hand, IEEE 1076.1 standard (informally VHDL-AMS) adds more capabilities of **modeling** analog and mixed-signal circuits. So analog/mixed modeling is possible, but design is not.

The description below is from the [IEEE 1076.1-2007](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1076.1-2007.html) page.

> This standard defines the IEEE 1076.1 language, a hardware description
>   language for the description and the simulation of analog, digital,
>   and mixed-signal systems. The language, also informally known as
>   VHDL-AMS, is built on IEEE Std 1076trade-2002 (VHDL) and extends it
>   with additions and changes to provide capabilities of **writing and
>   simulating analog and mixed-signal models**.

Comment: You have to buy the paper or is there a way to download it for free?

Comment: @Slav I also have no access to it. I just referred to the description.